# Is it possible to mount a docker image and then access it (RO) as a normal directory or mounted device?

Tags: docker

I would like to take a Docker image (let's say ubuntu:latest) and make something like:

```
> docker-image-mount ubuntu:latest my_little_ubuntu  
> cd my_little_ubuntu
> ls
/usr /var /bin etc.
```

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: This is definitely possible, because docker do it itself. But this is very dependent on particular storage driver (aufs or btrfs). I believe, answer is here https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/aufs/aufs.go. I'm interested in this questions and now gonna investigate it and write simple tool like docker-image-mount.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just investigated internal structure of how docker stores their images.
In case of `aufs` storage driver there is following directory layout (I assume, that docker lives in `/var/lib/docker`).

- `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` in this directory docker stores data of each image "layer". It is just a directory with files, which docker mounts in container root.
- `/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers` in this directory docker stores just text files. Each files contains list of layer ID's for certain image.

So docker itself does something like that:

```
DOCKER_AUFS_PATH="/var/lib/docker/aufs/"
DOCKER_AUFS_LAYERS="${DOCKER_AUFS_PATH}/layers/"
DOCKER_AUFS_DIFF="${DOCKER_AUFS_PATH}/diff/"

error() { echo "$@" 1>&2; }

if [ -z "${IMAGE}" ];
then
  error "Image is not specified"
  exit 1
fi;

if [ -z "${TARGET}" ];
then
  error "Target is not specified"
  exit 1
fi;

BRANCH="br"
while read LAYER; do
  BRANCH+=":${DOCKER_AUFS_DIFF}/${LAYER}=ro+wh"
done < "${DOCKER_AUFS_LAYERS}/${IMAGE}"

mount -t aufs -o "${BRANCH}" "${IMAGE}" "${TARGET}"
```

Where ${IMAGE} is ID of docker container, and ${TARGET} is existed directory in host filesystem where to mount image.

To unmount it just call:

`umount cf39b476aeec4d2bd097945a14a147dc52e16bd88511ed931357a5cd6f6590de`

As I mentioned in comment above, this is heavily depends on storage driver (and obviously on docker version), so I could not give you any guarantee that you will get this code working.

Comment: If some one wants to improve this code or extend it, welcome here https://github.com/kovyl2404/docker-image-mount/

Comment: Obvious caveat: if you modify your image, docker won't know about it... so could break your workflows.

Answer (score 8):

You could use Podman and Buildah to mount a container *image* (RW).

```
prompt:~ # podman pull ubuntu

prompt:~ # container=`buildah from ubuntu`

prompt:~ # echo $container
ubuntu-working-container

prompt:~ # mnt=`buildah mount $container`

prompt:~ # echo $mnt
/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/2b1...09b/merged

prompt:~ # ls $mnt
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  ...  usr  var

prompt:~ # buildah umount $container
```

If you actually want to mount a running or stopped *container*, you could mount it using the `podman mount` command.

Comment: Although it would make more sense to just do the latter... podman run image; podman ps -a; podman mount id