# Removing what was added in previous layer in docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to reduce the size of my docker image.  In my docker file, I do this:

```
FROM crystal/centos
MAINTAINER crystal

ADD ./rpms/test.rpm ./rpms/ 
RUN yum -y --nogpgcheck localinstall /rpms/test.rpm
```

from what I understand, the ADD command is in its own layer, and then RUN is in another layer.  So after I install the rpm, how do I go about deleting the initial `/rpms` directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this technique

```
RUN curl http://someaddress/test.rpm &&\
    yum -y --nogpgcheck localinstall /rpms/test.rpm &&\
    rm test.rpm
```

Comment: You can just RUN yum -y install http://someaddress/test.rpm if the rpm is hosted somewhere.

Comment: My situation is that - due to security reasons I am downloading the packages in the intermediate layer. Then, ADD'ing them to the final image. Followed by using RUN command to install the packages and delete the packages. My goal is to delete the downloaded packages once the RUN command installs them. Is there any way to a) combine the ADD and RUN into one layer; b) remove the ADD layer?

Answer (score 4):

you cannot remove data from previous layers. If the `/rpms/` folder is huge and you absolutely don't want its data in your docker image you have at least two solutions:

1. do not `ADD` the data (since it will commit a layer), instead use a **single** `RUN` instruction to:

   - download the rpm file
   - install the rpm file
   - delete the rpm file
2. [flatten your image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713551/how-to-flatten-a-docker-image) afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
RUN rm -rf /rpms
```

which will make the ultimate union file system smaller.  That is, df will report less usage.  It will not of course make the image database smaller, but rather very slightly larger.  If you want to avoid making your database larger, you can create your own yum repository and install directly from there.  This has the obvious downside that it will not be reproducible by anyone without access to your yum repo.

Answer (score 1):

In question about mounting docker image to host filesystem I've covered some internal structure of how docker stores their images. You can refer this question [Is it possible to mount a docker image and then access it (RO) as a normal directory or mounted device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575208/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-docker-image-and-then-access-it-ro-as-a-normal-direc)

In case of AUFS graph driver, docker (at least in version 1.2 or later) does:

- Store container layers in directory `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff`
- Keep list of layers which container consists of in simple text file `/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/${CONTAINER_ID}`.

So, if you desire to delete some intermediate layer from your container, you may try to delete particular line from `/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/${CONTAINER_ID}` and then remove corresponding directory from `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/`.

**NOTE: I didn't try this. This may doesn't work for you, or even may be dangerous.**

Comment: The major problem will be that the layer will be restored each time the image is built. I have to say IMO it is dangerous and generally a bad idea to play with the filesystem like this.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you.